# Is there any way to rearrange the following equation for x?

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics, lambert-w, projectile-motion

Is there any way to rearrange the following equation to get $x$ in terms of $\theta$? $g$, $k$ and $u$ are known constants, and $\theta$ and $x$ are unknowns.

$$\frac g{k^2}\ln(\frac {u \cos(\theta)-kx}{u \cos(\theta)})+x\tan(\theta)+\frac{gx}{ku\cos(\theta)}=0$$

My ultimate aim is to differentiate $x$ with respect to $\theta$, equate that expression to $0$, and thereby find a value for $\theta$ that maximises $x$; if there is a way to do this without rearranging for $x$, I would be very interested to hear it.

I have briefly looked into the Lambert W function, but as far as I can tell it can't be used here, as $\theta$ is an unknown.

Edit: I took $\frac {d}{d\theta}$, and got the following equation (rearranged for $x$). Can I use this to find the optimal value of $\theta$?

$$x=\frac {u^2\cos(\theta)}{ku+g\sin(\theta)}$$

Comment: Yes: you can use the Lambert W function. But also not really, in the way you probably intended.

Comment: @dbx so is there any way for me to find a value of theta that maximises x?

Comment: I don't see much hope of an analytic solution -- after substituting the expression found by Yves into the original, after some algebra, the equation can be put in the form $w \ln(-w) = c$ where both $w$ and $c$ are expressions involving $\theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed,

$$\frac{df(\theta,x)}{d\theta}=\frac{\partial f(\theta,x)}{\partial\theta}+\frac{dx}{d\theta}\frac{\partial f(\theta,x)}{\partial x}=0$$ so that $\dfrac{dx}{d\theta}$ cancels when $\dfrac{\partial f(\theta,x)}{\partial\theta}$ cancels.

I confirm the result

$$x=\frac {u^2\cos(\theta)}{ku+g\sin(\theta)},$$

but you still have to solve the initial equation for $\theta$, after plugging the expression of $x$. Which is ugly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I'm not particularly familiar with partial derivatives, could you guide me towards some useful sources for learning more about them? Or, as opposed to learning about them, would it just be easier for me to substitute my expression for x back into the original and solve for $\theta$, as you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this in the future:

I have spoken to my teacher, who recommended looking into implicit differentiation. Using this, we can solve for x, and plug it back into the original equation and solve for θ